# vscode python module intellisense doesn't work

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm developing a Python package with the following structure:

```
module_name
  |- __init__.py
  |- app.py
  |- filesystem
     - __init__.py
     - extend_filesystem.py
```

The `extend_filesystem.py` contains the following function with the displayed signature:

[function signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9BHn.jpg)

When I try to import the module inside `app.py` VScode doesn't show any useful information (like parameters hints or function's description)

[intellisen screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdLk5.gif)

I installed the Pylance extension, I set it as server Language and set the Python's interpreter (Python 3.7.1 32-bit in my case) for the entire workspace

I'm using Vscode Version 1.54.2

**Edit:**
within the same directory, the intellisense system shows all the information. So, how can I extend this behaviour in the entire package folder?

Comment: why post an image of the function definition

Comment: I think there is an issue open in vs code. please reference https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/5132 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4630

Answer (score 0):

According to the information you provided, I tested it in VS Code, and you could refer to the following:

[image]

1. When I use `Jedi` (default) as the language service of python:

   [image]

   In order to ensure that the code can run, we need to use:

   > `from filesystem.extend_filesystem import extend_file`
2. When I use `Pylance` as a language service for python:

   [image]

   In order to ensure that the code can run, we need to use:

   > ```
   > import sys 
   > sys.path.append("./")
   >
   > from emo.filesystem.extend_filesystem import extend_file
   > ```

In addition, it is recommended that you distinguish between the file name and the function name to avoid confusion during import.